# ASP.NET MVC Edit problem - "entity" data from controller aren't passed to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, editing

I'm pretty sure that I complicated my question. Sorry, I didn't know how to express myself. Situation is next :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        CreateTrainingModel editTrainingModel = new CreateTrainingModel();

        editTrainingModel.Training = training.GetByID(id);
        editTrainingModel.Player = player.GetAll();            

        return View(editTrainingModel);
    }
```

and Editor template for Html.EditorFor() :

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TrainingStatistics.Models.ViewModels.CreateTrainingModel>

@Html.ValidationSummary()

<table>
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Training.TrainingID) 

 <tr>
  <td>Training Date</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Training.Date"></td>
  <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Training.Date)</td>
 </tr> 

</table>
```

Problem is that when I want to edit this, data from model aren't passed to the view. I think that problem is because of using ViewModels and I'm doing something wrong here..When I try to update something which is consist of only one entity (example Player) and when I'm not using ViewModel everything is fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hrm, this looks tight and functional...

Comment: Problem was because I didn't specify value in input type for datepicker control... Using  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Training.Date, new { id = "datepicker" }) solved the problem.. or just value="@Model.Training.Date" ... cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create editor template for the view model.
You can see the exmaples of this below
http://www.codecapers.com/post/Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASPNET-MVC-2.aspx
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/21/htmleditorforscaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx